# MVC @Html.DisplayFor - Assigning the DisplayTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have a view model **OrderViewModel** and on it a class, "**CustomerViewModel**"

I would like to display it like this:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.CustomerViewModel)
```

How do I attribute the **CustomerViewModel** class so that MVC will render it with:

```
/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/MyUIForCustomerViewModel.cshtml
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [UIHint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.uihint(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute on property with CustomViewModel

```
[UIHint("MyUIForCustomerViewModel")]
public CustomViewModel CustomViewModel { get; set; }
```

Or you can name display tamplate same as class name:

```
 /Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/CustomerViewModel.cshml
```

You can also pass Template name to [Html.DisplayFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407420(v=vs.118).aspx) helper

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.CustomerViewModel, "MyUIForCustomerViewModel")
```